# change function not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#category_id").change(function() {   
        alert("Thanks for clicking.");
    });
</script>

echo $this->Form->input('category', array('id' =>'category_id',
    'options' => array('it' => 'IT',
    'contents' => 'Content writing',
    'logo' => 'Logo Designing'
    )));
```

when I select option from list change function doesn't work. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your jquery script inside `document.ready` as your element doesn't exist when the script is loaded.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#category_id").change(function() {   
      alert("Thanks for clicking.");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not yet include success file jquery.js in the view or layout default.ctp